# Loading items from entity framework created database into dropdownlistfor helper

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, html.dropdownlistfor

I have been struggling with a loading a display list of items from a database table that was created through the entity framework.

I have found code examples online but many have a static list of items created and then added to the dropdown list list like.
http://www.aspnetmvcninja.com/general/asp-net-mvc-dropdown-list-example. I found an article by Scott Allen that is the basis for what I have (http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2010/01/18/drop-down-lists-and-asp-net-mvc.aspx) but I think that issue is that Im not correctly loading the data into _jobs?

Here is the code that I have in my controller and other classes, any help or guidance is greatly appreciated as I feel that Im so close and yet not.

```
public class JobsController : Controller
{
  var tasks = db.JobTypes.Select(c => new SelectListItem {Value = c.JobTypeID.ToString(), Text = c.JobDescription});
  ViewBag.JobTypeAllNames = tasks;
  return View();
}
```

I have two classs that are being used for my entity framework code first. The Job class references the JobTypes class.

```
public class Job
{
    [Key]
    [Display(Name="Job ID")]
    public int JobID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Job Type")]
    public int JobTypesID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    private readonly List<JobType> _jobs;

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> JobTypeItems
    {
        get
        {
            return new SelectList(_jobs, "JobTypesID", "JobDescription",1);
        }
    }
}

public class JobType
{
    public int JobTypeID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Task")]
    public string JobDescription { get; set; }
}
```

In my view I have

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.JobTypesID, Model.JobTypeItems);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not going to compile:

```
public class JobsController : Controller
{
  var tasks = db.JobTypes.Select(c => new SelectListItem {Value = c.JobTypeID.ToString(), Text = c.JobDescription});
  ViewBag.JobTypeAllNames = tasks;
  return View();
}
```

You need to have an action that will return an `ActionResult` and I would use a model like you have within your view rather than use the `ViewBag`:

```
public class JobsController : Controller
{

  public ActionResult Index()
  {
    var model = new Job();
    var tasks = db.JobTypes.Select(c => new SelectListItem {Value =   c.JobTypeID.ToString(), Text = c.JobDescription});
    model.JobTypeItems = tasks;
    return View(model);
  }
}
```

ps You will need to adapt your `Job` model to include a setter and remove un-used `_jobs`:

```
public class Job
{
    [Key]
    [Display(Name="Job ID")]
    public int JobID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Job Type")]
    public int JobTypesID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> JobTypeItems
    {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

Comment: @BryanPritchett no problem. Thanks. :)